# Joining multiple DataFrames using SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have a DataFrame with Person data and also have like 20 more DataFrames with a common key *Person_Id*. I want to join all of them to the Person DataFrame to have all my data in the same DataFrame.

I tried both join and merge like this:

```
merge(df_person, df_1, by="Person_Id", all.x=TRUE)
```

and

```
join(df_person, df_1, df_person$Person_Id == df_1$Person_Id, "left")
```

In both of them, I find the same error. Both functions Join the Datasets in the right way but it duplicates the field *Person_Id*. Is there any way to tell those functions to not duplicate the *Person_Id* field?

Also, anyone knows a more efficient way to join all those DataFrames together?

Thanks you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other supported languages support simplified equi-join syntax, but it looks like it is not implemented in R so you have to do it the old way (rename and drop):

```
library(magrittr)

withColumnRenamed(df_1, "Person_Id", "Person_Id_") %>% 
  join(df_2, column("Person_Id") == column("Person_id_")) %>% 
  drop("Person_Id_")
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @user837195 this worked for me. I will have to do the same with evey DataFrame with the Main one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a lot of joins in SparkR it is worthwhile to make your own function to rename then join then remove the renamed column

```
DFJoin <- function(left_df, right_df, key = "key", join_type = "left"){

    left_df <- withColumnRenamed(left_df, key, "left_key")
    right_df <- withColumnRenamed(right_df, key, "right_key")

    result <- join(
        left_df, right_df,
        left_df$left_key == right_df$right_key,
        joinType = join_type)

    result <- withColumnRenamed(result, "left_key", key)
    result$right_key <- NULL

    return(result)

}

df1 <- as.DataFrame(data.frame(Person_Id = c("1", "2", "3"), value_1 = 
c(2, 4, 6)))
df2 <- as.DataFrame(data.frame(Person_Id = c("1", "2"), value_2 = c(3, 
6)))

df3 <- DFjoin(df1, df2, key = "Person_Id", join_type = "left")
head(df3)
    Person_Id value_1 value_2
1         3       6      NA
2         1       2       3
3         2       4       6
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @liamvt, this approach also worked for me!